# Oracle EMP - The list of those who earn more than any of the managers

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm a beginner in sql and I work on the EMP table on Oracle. I wonder how to display the list of those who earn more than any of the managers.
For those who don't know the structure of the EMP table :

```
EMPNO   ENAME   JOB       MGR     HIREDATE   SAL  DEPTNO
7839    KING    PRESIDENT   -   11/17/1981  5000    10
7698    BLAKE   MANAGER   7839  05/01/1981  2850    30
7782    CLARK   MANAGER   7839  06/09/1981  2450    10
7566    JONES   MANAGER   7839  04/02/1981  2975    20
7788    SCOTT   ANALYST   7566  12/09/1982  3000    20
7902    FORD    ANALYST   7566  12/03/1981  3000    20
7369    SMITH   CLERK     7902  12/17/1980  800     20
7499    ALLEN   SALESMAN  7698  02/20/1981  1600    30
7521    WARD    SALESMAN  7698  02/22/1981  1250    30
7654    MARTIN  SALESMAN  7698  09/28/1981  1250    30
```

Comment: Add a few more rows of sample data. Also specify the expected result. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: It can be done via co-related query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are a beginner - here are thoughts to help you figure out what to do:

1. try to write a query to find the salaries of the managers.
2. add to that query to find the minimum salary of those managers
3. now use that as a subquery, and find all employees who have a salary greater
4. From this list, remove the managers

you should be able to write these 4 queries by building upon the previous.

Comment: I'm not sure but I have write this query : select ename from emp where sal > (select min(sal) from emp where JOB = 'MANAGER');
Do you agree ?

Comment: i think close -but your query will also include managers - so maybe or maybe not what you want.

Comment: Okat so I just add "and JOB NOT LIKE 'MANAGER'" and this is my final query 
Thanks a lot !